# Emb a var text value inside href

Tags: javascript, html

I wanna make links that contain from 0 to 17 in the paragraph.
             as an href so I click the link I wanna 
        go)>
    For example, a list of links automatically written and embed on their same name.
    "test.com/1"
    "test.com/2"
    "test.com/3"
    "test.com/4"
    "test.com/5"

```
    <script>
    var text = "";
    var i;
    for (i = 301; i < 318; i++) {
      text += "www.test.com/videos/videos/" + i + ".mp4<br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>


    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var scrt_var = 10; 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't tell exactly what you were asking for, but this might help.

You can create elements on a page like this:

```
Link = document.createElement("a");
```

You can apply attributes to them like this:

```
Link.innerHTML = "some link text";
Link.href = "some link";
```

You can then append the element to the page in many ways such as:

```
document.body.append(Link);
```

With this, you can use a for loop to make many links:

```
for (i=0; i<18; i++) {
   Link = document.createElement("a");
   Br = document.createElement("br");
   Link.innerHTML = "some link text " + i;
   Link.href = "some link " + i;
   document.body.append(Link);
   document.body.append(Br);
}
```

The result will be:

```
some link text 0
some link text 1
some link text 2
some link text 3
some link text 4
some link text 5
some link text 6
some link text 7
some link text 8
some link text 9
some link text 10
some link text 11
some link text 12
some link text 13
some link text 14
some link text 15
some link text 16
some link text 17
```

With each link having the correct url.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what exactly you want. However, maybe you're looking for something similar to the following demo: https://jsfiddle.net/pxna8u19/

Code:

```
<div id="data"></div>
```

```
let elements = ""

for (let i = 0; i < 17; i++) {

  elements += "<a href ='www.test.com/videos/videos/" + i + ".mp4' target=_blank> Para " + i + " <a><br>"

}
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = elements;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But for "href=" the embed link should have "http:// or https://" at the beginning or it will link to the local website.

Comment: Yes, you can just add that. Could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    </body>

    <script>
        var text = "";
        for (i = 1; i < 17; i++) {
        text = "https://www.test.com/videos/videos/" + i + ".mp4";
        var link = document.createElement("A");
        link.href = text;
        link.innerHTML = text;
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
    }
    </script>
</html>
```